# Why is this valid C

Tags: c

I came across this code on [reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/r55bo/what_does_0_mean_in_c_stack_overflow/c430cp2). I would have thought that type conversions would have caused this to be invalid.

```
int a[3] = { { {1, 2}, {3, 4}, 5, 6 }, {7, 8}, {9}, 10 };
```

On clang, I get a few warnings about excessive elements and braces in a scalar initializer. But the contents of `a` is `[1, 7, 9]`.

Is this actually legitimate, and if it is, could someone explain what exactly is going on?

Comment: With gcc I get 24 Warnings. Great question. I live & learn:-)

Comment: Yay gcc!  At least you get a warning.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The excess elements are just ignored.  There are two parts of **6.7.8 Initialization** that you care about.  First, from paragraph 17:

> Each brace-enclosed initializer list has an associated current object. When no designations are present, subobjects of the current object are initialized in order according to the type of the current object: array elements in increasing subscript order, structure members in declaration order, and the first named member of a union.

That one explains why you get 1, 7, and 9 - the current object gets set by those braces. Then as to why it doesn't care about the extras, from paragraph 20:

> ... only enough initializers from the list are taken to account for the elements or members of the subaggregate or the first member of the contained union; any remaining initializers are left to initialize the next element or member of the aggregate of which the current subaggregate or contained union is a part.

Comment: But why? And why is it valid to pass nested elements where there are no struct/union/class types?

Comment: would you mind sharing the url of the standard you're quoting?

Comment: The answer to "why", I guess, is that it's not specifically disallowed, so implementations have to accept it.

Comment: I'd call it "a bug in the standard".  Or maybe "feature"; after all, it's documented!

Comment: There's probably some weird old code they wanted to keep legal.

Comment: @torek `It's not a bug! It's an undocumented feature!` ~ Popular programming excuse/quote.

Comment: Thanks Carl! I didn't think initializer lists were defined in that manner.

Comment: Not quite defined enough for my taste, I have to say... =)

Comment: I don't think it's a valid declaration. See my answer I think it's a clear constraint violation of C99, 6.7.8p1.

Answer (score 4):

```
  int a[3] = { { {1, 2}, {3, 4}, 5, 6 }, {7, 8}, {9}, 10 };
```

is invalid.

It is invalid for the same reasons `int b[1] = {1, 2};` is invalid: because C99 says

> (C99, 6.7.8p1) "No initializer shall attempt to provide a value for an object not contained within the entity being initialized."

The last element `10` in `a` initializers attempts to provide a value for an object not contained within the entity being initialized.

Comment: I would love to hear a good debate on the different assertions made by the reference you have cited, and the second reference cited by Carl.  Seems to be a clear conflict within the standards, which will likely lead to differences in compiler implementations until it is resolved. +1 for pointing out the diff.