# Why char initialization difference? C

Tags: c, initialization

Why are those two ways of initializing an array different from each other?

The first initialization gives me a compiler warning:

whereas the second one just works fine..

```
char *c_array_1[] = { {'a','b','c','d','e'}, {'f','g','h','i','j'} };

char *c_array_2[] = {"abcde","fghij"};
```

Comment: One difference is that the latter includes a terminating NUL character in each string... which you probably wanted.

Comment: The first one is not correct because you say `T name[] = { e1, e2 }`. Are e1 and e2 really compatible with type T (`char *`) in your first initialization? In your second one you make e1 and e2 `const char *` which is allowed to be converted to `char *` implicitly. However you're still not allowed to change those elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, in the C language, string literals (like: `"abcde"`) automatically get storage allocated for them in the background of the compiler.

So, when you do

```
char *c_array_2[] = {"abcde","fghij"};
```

The compiler can, to some degree, change that to:

```
char *c_array_2[] = {Some_Pointer, Some_Other_Pointer};
```

However, for the other example:

```
char *c_array_1[] = { {'a','b','c','d','e'}, {'f','g','h','i','j'} };
```

The compiler will attempt to initialize. This will cause this line of code to be converted to the following (And probably push out a few warnings):

```
char *c_array_1[] = {'a', 'f'};
```

And then this is certainly not what you want (`'a'` is very likely not a valid pointer. You can see some more information on why the initialization happens like that from this question: [Why is this valid C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9792162/why-is-this-valid-c)

Comment: More exactly it will take the first char as an int and then attempt to convert it to a pointer, then it will have excess elements left over.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour: You're totally right. I forgot about the correct rules for how aggregate initialization works.

Comment: Can you tell why it will take the first char as an int?