# Creates two pointers? char *name[] = {"xxx", "yyy"}

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

Somebody told me as an answer to my last [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21634149/why-char-initialization-difference-c) that

```
char *name[] = {"xxx", "yyy"}
```

is changed by the compiler to

```
char *name[] = {Some_Pointer, Some_Other_Pointer};
```

I tried the following for understanding:

```
printf("%p\n", &name);
printf("%p\n", name);
printf("%s\n", *name);
printf("%c\n", **name);
```

So as an output it gives me:

```
0xfff0000f0
0xfff0000f0
xxx
x
```

Can you explain to me how the address of the pointer "name" is the same as the address where the pointer "name" is pointing to?
From my understanding the pointer "name" itself occupies 8 bytes. How can the first string "xxx" which occupies 4 bytes in memory be at the same location as the pointer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, when you have any array like `name` in C, the **value** of the array is the address of its first element. Note that this value is not stored in some variable. It is used as an immediate value in the compiled assembly code. So it doesn't makes sense to think about its **address**.

Second, since an array is stored in memory as a bunch of consecutive location, the address of the array is defined the address of the first element. So for any array `A` you have the following equality of addresses

```
 &(A[0]) == A == &A
```

It doesn't change anything to that if you have array of pointer or whatever.

Comment: This is a good explanation thank you. Eventhough I'm still not entirely enlightened... I wonder how the array "name" has a size of 16 bytes (because it is 2 pointers) and both strings are 4 bytes long.... Where are the strings and the pointers located in memory?

Comment: The answer is: the string are stored somewhere (read-only static allocation page) ! That is the compiler decide to place them where it places its global constants. On the other hands, the two pointer to the string are stored in the array.

Comment: So the address of the strings are name[0] and name[1] ? So as @mahendiran.b is mentioning: if I use %p as format I get the address of the string and if I use %s as a format I get the value of the string?

Comment: @Jan: `sizeof name` is 16 because this answer is partly wrong about arrays. It is not correct that the value of an array is the address of its first element. The name of the array does stand for the array, not its value. However, any array expression (whether it is a simple name or is calculated somehow) is automatically converted to the address of its first element **except** when it is the operand of `sizeof`, `_Alignof`, or `&` or when it is a string literal used to initialize an array. (This rule is in C 2011 6.3.2.1 3.)

Comment: Eric Postpischil: strictly speaking you are indeed right. Due to the level of the question, I didn't wanted to go into pedantic subtleties. Does it seems more correct to you if I say that "Evaluating an array returns the address of its first element" ?

Answer (score 4):

To view the address of "xxx" you should print `printf("%p\n", name[0]);` like this. Surely address of `name and address of "xxx" wont be the same`. Here `name` is `array of pointer` which holds the address of "xxx and yyy".

```
printf("%p\n", &name);
printf("%p\n", name);
printf("%p\n", name[0]); address of "xxx"
printf("%p\n", name[1]); address of "yyy"
```

Answer (score 2):

The type of `name` decays from `array of char*` to `pointer to char*` and its value is the address of the first element of the array.  The expression `&name` is of type `pointer to char* [2]` and its value is the address of the array which is the same as the address of the array's first element.

It seems that you misunderstood the representation of array in C.  There isn't a "meta" object representing an array in C.  An array in C consists only its elements in sequence.  Thus applying operator & to the array name simply gets you the address of the array's first element (value-wise, not type-wise).

If you try writing:

```
char (*p)[2] = &name;
printf("%p", &p);
```

This prints out the `address of a pointer to an array`, and it will certainly be a different value than `name` and `&name`.

Answer (score 2):

> Can you explain to me how the address of the pointer "name" is the same as the address where the pointer "name" is pointing to?

`&name` give you the address of the entire array of pointers (which holds the pointers to the strings `XXX` and `YYY`) and `name` will give you the pointer to its first element, i.e, `XXX` (after decay). Since the address of the first byte is said to be the address of the variable (array), the value of `&name` is same as that of `name` but both of `&name` and `name` are of different type.

Answer (score 2):

> From my understanding the pointer "name" itself occupies 8 bytes. How
>   can the first string "xxx" which occupies 4 bytes in memory be at the
>   same location as the pointer?

That's because `name` is an array, not a pointer. A pointer is a variable which stores the address of another variable of the same type but an array is a contiguous blocks of memory bound to (referenced by) a single identifier. Basically, it's a different type. Please note that arrays are not first class objects in C -  you can't pass an array to or return an array from a function.

The confusion arises because an array in many situations decays (implicitly converted) into a pointer to its first element. Some case where this happens are:

```
void f(char p[]); // p is a pointer, not an array

// This is exactly the same as

void f(char *p); 

char s[] = {'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'};
f(s);   // here s decays to a pointer to its first element

// another example

char t = "hello"[1]; // the string literal decays to a pointer to its first element
```

Here are some cases where an array stays an array(does not decay into a pointer):

```
char s[] = "hello";
char *t = "hello"; // string literal decays into a pointer

printf("%d", sizeof s);  // prints 5
printf("%d", sizeof t);  // prints 4 or 8 depending on the pointer size on the machine
printf("%d", sizeof *t);  // prints 1

// taking your example

char *name[] = {"xxxx", "yyyy"}; // yet another case where string literals decay to a pointer

printf("%p", name); // name is an array but here decays to a pointer
printf("%p", &name); // &name is a pointer to an array of 2 pointers to characters
```

Though `name`, `&name` evaluate to the same value in the `printf` call, they are not the same type. To see the difference do this:

```
printf("%p", name + 1);
printf("%p", &name + 1);

printf("%d", *(&name + 1) - name); // prints the length of the array
```

To sum up, arrays and pointers are different types. Pointers store addresses, arrays store values of type they are defined to store. In some situations arrays evaluate to the address of its first element. That's where the similarity ends between arrays and pointers.